# Azure_file for docker composer in Azure cloud

Tags: azure, docker

Trying to create [ChirpStack](https://github.com/brocaar/chirpstack-docker) Docker-Compose container in Azure cloud:

```
docker login azure
docker context create aci myacicontext
docker context use myacicontext
docker compose --file .\docker-compose.yml up
```

Got error:

```
cannot use ACI volume, required driver is “azure_file”, found “”
```

What I do wrong?

UPD
Content of **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "3"

services:
  chirpstack-network-server:
    image: chirpstack/chirpstack-network-server:3
    volumes:
      - ./configuration/chirpstack-network-server:/etc/chirpstack-network-server

  chirpstack-application-server:
    image: chirpstack/chirpstack-application-server:3
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./configuration/chirpstack-application-server:/etc/chirpstack-application-server

  chirpstack-gateway-bridge:
    image: chirpstack/chirpstack-gateway-bridge:3
    ports:
      - 1700:1700/udp
    volumes:
      - ./configuration/chirpstack-gateway-bridge:/etc/chirpstack-gateway-bridge

  chirpstack-geolocation-server:
    image: chirpstack/chirpstack-geolocation-server:3
    volumes:
      - ./configuration/chirpstack-geolocation-server:/etc/chirpstack-geolocation-server

  postgresql:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - ./configuration/postgresql/initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - postgresqldata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  redis:
    image: redis:5-alpine
    volumes:
      - redisdata:/data

  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:2
    ports:
      - 1883:1883
    volumes: 
      - ./configuration/eclipse-mosquitto/mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf

volumes:
  postgresqldata:
  redisdata:
```

Comment: Could you please share your docker-compose.yml?

Comment: I have updated question body with yml

Comment: What way are you going to deploy Docker container: WebApp, Container Instances, Kubernetes?

Comment: I'm planning to create Container Instances

Comment: Any updates on this problem? Does it solve you problem?

Answer (score 6):

The error already shows you that it requires the driver `azure_file` for the volume when you use the Azure file share as the persistent volume. It should be like this:

```
volumes:
  postgresqldata:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: myfileshare
      storage_account_name: mystorageaccount
  redisdata:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: myfileshare
      storage_account_name: mystorageaccount
```

See more details about the File Share for the ACI through Docker Compose [here](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-integration/#using-azure-file-share-as-volumes-in-aci-containers).

Comment: Hey Charles, how do I install `azure_file` driver for Windows? The official repo has been archived for `cloudstor`

Comment: @Shantanu You don't need to install. Just set it.